# How do I acquire an immortal horse?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have purchased a horse or two on Skyrim and I accidentally keep killing them with fall damage getting to my destination. I heard of a horse given by the Dark Brotherhood that does not die to fall damage is it true, and if so how can I get it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Shadowmere is a horse in The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim, originally owned
>   by Lucien Lachance. Astrid lets the Dragonborn borrow Shadowmere to
>   travel to the Dawnstar Sanctuary for the quest The Cure for Madness.
>   She then gives him to the Dragonborn as a reward for completing the
>   quest

From http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Shadowmere_%28Skyrim%29

Regarding Shadowmere's immortality:

> Shadowmere is not essential and can die, unlike his counterpart in
>   Oblivion. However, 10 days later, he will respawn at the location of
>   his death. If Shadowmere dies in a river or lake, he will respawn
>   after 10 days in the black pool near the Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary.

[Source](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Shadowmere)

Comment: is that horse immortal though

Comment: @Skyrim_impressed He is kind of. Check out my edit.

Comment: thanks I understand because I'm tired of wasting money on horses that die and it usually costs me 1000 gold

Answer (score 9):

If you have the Dawnguard DLC you can obtain [Arvak](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Arvak), an undead horse.

> Arvak is a horse that can be summoned from the Soul Cairn after completing Soul Cairn Horse Quest. He can be summoned with the apprentice level conjuration spell Summon Arvak.

All you need to do to obtain him is progress through the Dawnguard main quest until you are able to enter the Soul Cairn, then complete [This quest](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Soul_Cairn_Horse_Quest).

Comment: so in the "Dawn Guard" DLC if I were to continue to go through the main quests I would get a soul shard or incantation I could get an undead horse. Is that what you're trying to tell me??

Comment: Yes, you learn a Conjuration spell called Summon Arvak. Officially, Arvak is summoned for 60 seconds, but actually he sticks around as long as you ride him. I avoided horses through most of the game because I knew riding at full gallop sometimes causes the game to crash, but I'm finding him useful. One thing I haven't tested is whether you have to keep carrying his skull around in order to cast the spell.

Comment: I should add, though, that I don't think you can even start the Dawnguard quests until level 10, and you have to complete some tough quests just to get to the Soul Cairn, which is pretty tough, too, so it might not be viable. On the other hand, Shadowmere might be equally tough to get.

Comment: im level 20 or 21 so i'll be fine

Comment: I should also say I now have shadowmere and it is immortal in some cases because I fought two dragons with him and he took their attention and didn't loose any health what so ever and he was bitten caught on fire shot by bandits and other stuff but I love shadowmere he can actually fight for you as well he actually saved me from a sabertooth cat

Comment: It does seem like a pretty cool horse ... I watched a friend play with Shadowmere. Sadly, it's not available if you opt to destroy the Dark Brotherhood instead. I think Arvak is available no matter which side you pick for Dawnguard, but Arvak doesn't fight. The other creatures you can learn to summon on that quest do, though, so I guess it's all good.